# Get the records from SQL table which matches on the same date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

How to find the all the records which are having multiple status for the same account Id (doesn't matter what status it's belong) on the same Date, doesn't matter about the time, but Date is important

Expected Result should as be mentioned in below table, I should pick the data which are having multiple status on the same day for the same account Id

| AccountId | Status | lastupdatedTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | DISB | 2023-09-07 06:30:30.000 |
| 12345 | SET | 2023-09-07 06:34:30.000 |
| 32341 | REB | 2023-09-07 14:30:30.000 |
| 32341 | D | 2023-09-07 15:31:30.000 |
| 52355 | SET | 2023-09-09 14:30:30.000 |
| 52355 | D | 2023-09-09 15:31:30.000 |

Sample table data :

```
CREATE TABLE PaymentRecord
(
    accountid BIGINT,
    Status varchar(10),
    lastupdatedTimestamp DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (12345, 'DISB', '2023-09-07 16:30:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (12345, 'SET', '2023-09-07 16:34:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (12346, 'D', '2023-09-07 11:30:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (22341, 'CLR', '2023-09-08 13:30:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (32341, 'REB', '2023-09-08 14:30:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (32341, 'D', '2023-09-08 15:31:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (42325, 'CLR', '2023-09-09 11:30:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (52355, 'SET', '2023-09-09 14:30:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (52355, 'D', '2023-09-09 15:31:30.000')
INSERT INTO PaymentRecord (accountid, Status, lastupdatedTimestamp) 
VALUES (52355, 'SK', '2023-09-10 16:31:30.000')
```

I have tried the following , but that did not work based on the expected result.

```
SELECT DISTICNT
    AccountId,
    Status,
    CONVERT (date, LastUpdatedTimestamp)
FROM
    PaymentRecord
WHERE
    LastUpdatedTimestamp BETWEEN '2023-09-07' AND '2023-09-11'
ORDER BY
    AccountId,
    CONVERT (date, LastUpdatedTimestamp),
    Status DESC
```

Comment: 2023-09-07 is not between 2023-09-08 and 2023-09-11.  Please explain why you would expect account 12345 to be in your output.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry it was typo mistake - I corrected, 12345     - I need that in output because it has multiple status on the same DATE

Comment: In your attempt you didn't try to filter out rows that have only one status on a day.  Isn't that what you want?  So that account 22341 is omitted?  What if there was an additional row like 32341, 'SK', 2023-09-10?  Would that be included in the output or not?

Comment: `DATETIME` in MS SQL Server is the wrong type for tracking a timestamp such as “last updated”. That type lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, so it cannot represent a moment, a point on the timeline. Instead, use [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Furthermore, `datetime` is outmoded, legacy, with Microsoft recommending you choose another. See [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: So all relevant rows must be within the date range, not just one of them (probably the final one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to understand your question.

But with your `WHERE` I can not reproduce your wanted result.

The concept is easy, make a sub-select where you get the accountid and date of the criteria more than one status at a date and join it to the main query.

```
select p1.AccountId
  ,convert(date,p1.LastUpdatedTimestamp),Status 
from PaymentRecord p1
  JOIN
  
  (SELECT AccountId,convert(date,LastUpdatedTimestamp) as LastUpdatedTimestamp
  FROM  PaymentRecord
 where LastUpdatedTimestamp between '2023-09-08' and '2023-09-11'
  GROUP BY AccountId,convert(date,LastUpdatedTimestamp)
HAVING COUNt(DISTINCT Status) > 1) p2 
  ON p1.AccountId = p2.AccountId AND convert(date,p1.LastUpdatedTimestamp) = p2.LastUpdatedTimestamp
  Order by p1.AccountId, p1.LastUpdatedTimestamp,Status desc
```

| AccountId | (No column name) | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32341 | 2023-09-08 | REB |
| 32341 | 2023-09-08 | D |
| 52355 | 2023-09-09 | SET |
| 52355 | 2023-09-09 | D |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RSHT9zVQ)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM PaymentRecord pr1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM PaymentRecord pr2
    WHERE pr1.AccountId = pr2.AccountId
    AND pr1.Status <> pr2.Status
    AND CAST(pr1.lastupdatedTimestamp AS DATE) = CAST(pr2.lastupdatedTimestamp AS DATE)
)
AND pr1.lastupdatedTimestamp BETWEEN '2023-09-07' AND '2023-09-11'
```